# tengo un problema con las rutas en el codigo de netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, msql

Miren resulta que un amigo que ya es desarrollador de software me mijo que mi problema con el netbeans no es el programa ni los conectores jar dice que no puse bien en el código las rutas de donde se ubica el documento para que pueda correrlo netbeans esta es la ruta que yo coloque [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y mi amigo me esta diciendo que donde corre el programa me esta diciendo cuales son los errores [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito que alguien me explique como puedo escribir las rutas sin equivocarme como escribo las rutas para que se pueda crear el documento itextpdf

Comment: Por favor, sustituye captura de pantalla por texto: es más fácil tanto para el que pregunta como para el que responde copiar y pegar texto y es mucho más legible.Te recomiendo que completes el [tour] de bienvenida y leas [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes que nada para la próxima has como dijo Pablo, es mucho mas facil si envias pegas el texto.

Tres sugerencias que podrian ayudarte a resolver tu problema:

**1ro.** Por lo que veo en el error estas intentando usar /Desktop. Pero en cambio usas /Documents/BD_alumnos.

**2do.** Usa LOGS para ir orientandote. Si no tienes un sistema para instalar dependencias al menos usa System.out.println(). Puedes visualizar el valor que esta tomando el string "ruta", ver las propiedades de "documento", etc.

**3ro.** Puedes setear para que cree un nuevo archivo si no lo encuentra, como con el ejemplo a continuación:

```
Document document = new Document();
File tuArchivo = new File("reporte.pdf");
tuArchivo.createNewFile(); // si ya existe no hace nada.
FileOutputStream oFile = new FileOutputStream(tuArchivo, false);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, oFile);
document.open();
...
```

Espero que alguna de las posibles soluciones te haya sido de utilidad.
Saludos